# Upload files with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

For our customer, I have to make a mail backup system that backups everything sent (subject, body, attachments, headers, ...)

But i'm stuck with the file uploads via curl.

This is my code so far:

```
$filesBackup = array('api_key' => 'xxx', 'files' => array());

                    foreach ($attachment as $att) {

                        $filesBackup['files'][] = new \CURLFile($att[0]);


                    $request = curl_init('http://xxx/webhooks/uploadtos3.php');
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
                    curl_setopt(
                        $request,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($filesBackup));
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_exec($request);
                    curl_close($request);
```

The problem here is that the filepath (`$att[0]`) is the following: "http://xxx/uploads/zonnepanelen/file.pdf"

So the only thing I receive at the uploadtos3.php is this array:

```
array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(89) "http://xxx/uploads/zonnepanelen/file.pdf"
      ["mime"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["postname"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [cURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Comment: i think the file which needs to upload should be in same path where files is

Answer (score 0):

update code with below one

```
$filesBackup['files'][]  should contain below keys?

array(
      'file' =>
          '@'            . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
          . ';filename=' . $_FILES['file']['name']
          . ';type='     . $_FILES['file']['type']
    )
```

Comment: I cannot use $_FILES because the only reference to the file I receive is a path like this "http://www.xxx.xx/uploads/file.pdf", and '@'.$file is deprecated in php 5.5 I guess?

Comment: ok den just get the file name and type from the link and add in array. check and see